# Development of a Web Application(CRM) in GWT

Tags: java, web-applications, gwt

I am student. Currently, I am experienced with Core Java and very introductory Servlets and JSPs concepts.

For my summer internship, I have a task at hand where I am to develop a social CRM for a small startup.

I am very new to web development, I have no prior experience in this field, I am familiar with the technologies involved though, however I want to start off now and develop a good project in the summers.

I want to base my project on Java, I am considering using GWT for all client side AJAX work along with a J2EE server.

Would this be a right decision on my part? What is the learning curve involved with GWT? Can I really start off with something like a small CRM without doing nothing more than a HelloWorld previously?

Need some suggestions as to how should I kick start my work and progress quickly with concepts and my project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop a good project, like you say, then I believe this is a very fine choice. It's certainly not the easiest one (you could probably hack something quickly with PHP etc.), but I'd say that it really pays off.

I would suggest to follow the official tutorial and the remainder of the official documentation (stay away from the "Editors" framework for now though, it's madness at the moment.)

If you already have a solid background in Core Java, and if you get the right picture of how GWT works (eg which code is transformed to JavaScript / when HTTP requests will occur / ...) I think you can absolutely do it. Make sure to get some solid HTML/CSS and a little bit of JavaScript background first.

I must add, that I would personally *not* go the Roo route (sorry @jgrabowski) - especially not at first <sub>(probably not ever, even though Roo is probably a very good tool, if you like such tools.)</sub>

- Understand the GWT technology,
- create a few very simple prototype apps (just for fun),
- then learn to apply best architecture practices, and improve your code.

And maybe you'll find, that a different architecture may even work better for your app (Just as an example: In the case of the largest application I'm currently working on, the generally-suggested MVP architecture would simply not work very well, at least not the way it's usually presented. So it's sometimes better to form a good solid understanding first, instead of blindly copying "best practices". Then you can make an informed decision, and develop a good project!)

Comment: I am working on it but somehow intimidated by the sheer amount of *new stuff* to be learnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can start playing with Spring's Roo and generate GWT skeleton of your application. Then you can analyze it, try to understand it, improve it (and even remove Roo from it afterwards:-).
Roo is able to generate well architected GWT application that is inline with current best practices, so I believe it might be good start for you.

Comment: Where can I get started from?

Comment: There is a getting started page: http://www.springsource.org/roo/start. After Chris's comment I think that indeed Roo might be the second step, not first. You can learn the basics from Google's GWT docs and then see how Roo app is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent source for exploring GWT in depth.

I would stronly recommend the book "Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development", as of now the book is quite updated on GWT, GAE and the APIs.

https://www.packtpub.com/google-app-engine-java-and-gwt-application-development/book

Answer (score 0):

In recent months the GWT Activities and Places pattern has matured.

The example covered at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html gives a broad introduction to the pattern.  The downloadable sample will lead demonstrate how to 'slice' your application into Activities and Places.  This pattern will take away some of your 'architecutre' concerns - you can just go with the flow and do it the A & P way.

Note, however the intro page and the demo code are very light on UI.  Separate to your architecture planning you'll need to get up to speed on laying out a GWT app - but that's also covered well in the GWT articles.  As @Chris-Lercher suggested, create a couple of UI prototypes that you're happy to throw away to get you started.